# Dynamic subdomain pages with .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, subdomain

I have my directory like this:

- /index.php (website main page)
- /sites

  - site1
  - site2
  - site3

---

1. when I go to `site1.example.com`, i want it to show `example.com/sites/site1/index.php`
2. when I go to `site1.example.com/page1`, i want it to show the file `example.com/sites/site1/page1.php`

how can i do that? thanks!

Comment: Aren't subdomains handled by the domain registrar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume all your subdomains point to the same place as the main domain, so `subdomain.example.com` and `example.com` point to the same place.

Try something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the root of the main site:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude requests for the www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Requests for the site root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ sites/%1/index.php [L]

# Requests that are "assumed" to be .php files
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ sites/%1/$1.php [L]

# All other requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^sites/ sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This assumes that a valid URL-path does not contain a dot.

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the *CondPattern* (ie. the *subdomain*) and `$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

However, how do you want to handle non-PHP files and other static resources?

---

> Also, how can I do a 404 page?

You can define a custom error document. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

However, you'll need to make an exception at the top of your `.htaccess` file to prevent this from being rewritten by the directives that follow. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^errors/ - [L]
```

Comment: This almost works. here are the problems: 1. when to go to `subdomain.example.com`, it says: `/sites/subdomain/.php`. it should default to `index.php`. also, if I type in `subdomain.example.com/index.php`, it shows me a blank page but when it remove the `.php`, it works.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully address those other situations.

Comment: thanks! better now. 1.) when it go to `subdomain.example.com`, it shows me to: `example.com/sites/subdomain/sites/subdomain/.php`. it should just show me `example.com/sites/subdomain/index.php`. Notice how it repeats it twice and it does not say index at the end. 2.) Also, how can I do a 404 page? if `subdomain.example.com/page2` does not exist, show error page: `example.com/404`. thanks

Comment: I've updated the code slightly. Can you also make sure you got my previous update (I updated it again quickly _after_ my previous comment above). I've also added some notes about custom error documents. Can you just confirm... you aren't being redirected are you? ie. you're not actually seeing a URL of the form `example.com/sites/subdomain/index.php` in the browsers address bar are you? This should be hidden.

Comment: Thanks so much. Okay, everything is working now except for two things. I go to `http://www.example.com/test` and it try's to show `/sites/www/test.php`. how can we disable it if it's just `www.` or nothing before it? Also the 404 error page. I put `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and i put `RewriteRule ^/ - [L]`. it just says the URL was not found on this server. a 404 not found error was encountered when trying to use an error document.

Comment: Okay everything works now except for one thing. It does not show the proper page. It just shows a blank page. For example, `subdomain.example.com` is supposed to show index.php page but it shows a blank page instead. Any page that is not a 404 error will show a blank page. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I've added an exception for the www subdomain. The code already excludes requests for the bare domain (ie. `http://example.com/...`). If your error document is simply `/404.php` then change the `RewriteRule` to: `RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]`. If you have many custom error documents then it's easier to contain these in their own subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks!. I added a comment above before you posted your last comment. It just shows a blank page

Comment: By "blank" do you mean you get a document returned but nothing is visible? Or you are literally getting _nothing_ returned? If the former then you need to check your client side paths to static resources (CSS, JS, etc). How are you generating these pages? Are they completely static?

Comment: When I click view source, I get nothing, not even the HTML content. I know it's a valid page

Comment: Foolish me. I forgot to replace the `example.com` with my domain. lol. But the problem that remains is the 404 page does not show up. it still says the default 404 message.

Comment: Make sure the _exception_ (ie. `RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L]` directive) is at the top of your script, before the existing mod_rewrite directives. However, this is really secondary to the question asked... if this answered your question then please mark it as accepted and optionally upvote any answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Setup a [Wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)
2. Write a rule for your .htaccess

The rule could look like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/sites/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

That's it.

Comment: Does not work at all. it takes redirects me endlessly.